# Find base in a $4\times 4$ matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Determine a base in the matrix $A$ and determine dimension of $\ker(A)$ and dimension of $\operatorname{Im}(A)$. With 
>   $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&-2&4&-1\\3&-1&2&-1\\-1&-3&6&-1\\-12&-1&\alpha&2\end{pmatrix},\;\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$$

My attempt:

It is easy to calculate and see that $\det(A)=0$ and many other determinants in $A$ are equal to $0$.
So I found one which is not, therefore $\det\begin{pmatrix}-1&2&-1\\-3&6&-1\\-1&\alpha&2\end{pmatrix}=2(\alpha-2)$

So this determinant is $\neq0$ iff $\alpha \neq2$.

Therefore $\operatorname{rank}(A)=3$ and the dimension of the base is $3$, right? Also
does the base equal to all the column vectors I found in this determinant? So then $\dim_{\mathbb{R}}\ker(A)= n - \operatorname{rank}(A) = 4 - 3 = 1$ and $\dim_{\mathbb{R}}\operatorname{Im}(A) = \operatorname{rank}(A) = 3$?

Comment: Yes, and for $\alpha=2$,  $\operatorname{rank}(A) = 2$, $\dim_{\mathbb{R}}\ker(A)=4-2=2$.

Comment: @RobertZ so the base I found with the column vectors of *that* determinant is still correct?

Comment: For $\alpha\not=2$, you can take as base columns 2,3,4. For $\alpha=2$, take  columns 3,4.

Comment: @RobertZ so the vectors should be still of length $n$?

Comment: Yes, they should be of "length" $4$. A base in $\mathbb{R}^4$ is made of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: @RobertZ Okay, thank you, But what If I have a matrix with m lines and n columns, and $m < n$. Actually let $(m = 3)$ and $(n = 4)$ and $rank(A) = 3$, how do I choose the Base, and can there be a base? Also it has to be with vectors of "length" 3? and what are the dimensions?

Comment: @RobertZ Sorry if i'm bothering with a lot of question but I really want to understand this.

Comment: A base of the image of $A$ is made of  $d=\operatorname{rank}(A)$ colums of the matrix $A$. Choose $d$ columns such that the determinant of a submatrix $d\times d$ of such columns is not zero.

Comment: @RobertZ and what about the dimensions? Same formulas?